# Are there any limits to what can be a cohort?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

A player wants to plan on recruiting a Unicorn cohort.

I can't find anything that restricts cohorts to humanoids, or player races etc. Can a Magical Beast be recruited as a cohort?

Answer (score 2):

**You can recruit any creature as a cohort which has a listed level adjustment/ECL, with DM's permission.**

"Special Cohorts", *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p.199:

> With the DM's permission, a leader may seek out a special cohort who is not a member of the standard PC races (the common races).

"Monster Cohorts and the Leadership Feat", *Savage Species*, p.35:

> In the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, Table 2–27 provides a few special cohorts along with their level equivalents, but you need not limit yourself to a short list of thirteen monsters when any viable creature from the *Monster Manual* now has a starting ECL (see Appending 2: Compiled Tables). The DM can work with players, if he or she approves the use of the Leadership feat, to generate a monster cohort. Refer to the cohort level provided by table 2–25 and choose a monster with equal or lesser starting ECL. Remember that regardless of his Leadership score, a character cannot attract a cohort whose level (or starting ECL, in this case) is equal to or higher than his own.

In the specific case of the unicorn: According to the table in the Dungeon Master's Guide, a unicorn is equivalent to an 8th level character for the purpose of taking him as a cohort. Technically the owner "must be a human, elf, or half-elf maiden", but that's purely thematic and it would not be unbalanced of the DM to ignore that requirement.

Comment: What if the unicorn refuses to ignore that requirement?